# About idempotent and invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I get a square matrix $A$ is idempotent when $A^2 = A$.

How can you prove that if $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix that is idempotent and invertible, then 
$A = I$??

I'm quite confused on this.

Any help much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Take $A^2=A$. Multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is invertible and $A^2 = A$, then you have

$$ A^{-1}AA = A^{-1}A$$

i.e.

$$ A = I$$

Answer (score 2):

Well, use what you have
$$I = AA^{-1} = A^2A^{-1} = A$$

Answer (score 2):

If you know determinants, then

$$A^2 = A \tag{*}$$

$$\implies \det(A^2)=\det(A)$$

$$\implies \det(A)^2=\det(A)$$

$$\implies \det(A) = 0 \ \text{or} \ 1$$

If $0$, then singular. If $1$, then $A^{-1}$ exists. Multiply $A^{-1}$ on both sides of $(*)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $A^2 = A$ gives us $(A^2-A) = 0$ , i.e. $A(A- I) = 0$. Now pre-multiplying $A^{-1}$ on both side we get $$A^{-1}A(A- I) = 0 \Rightarrow (A-I) = 0 \Rightarrow A =I$$